# How can I get the most expensive item from the following dict

Tags: python

text file:

```
1: Mercedes, 200, 10000USD
2: BMW, 150, 12000USD
3: Jeep, 30, 8000USD
```

```
dict = {'1:': ('Mercedes,', '200,', '10000USD'),
        '2:': ('BMW,', '150,', '12000USD'),
        '3:': ('Jeep,', '30,', '8000USD')}
```

stored as:

```
dict{id: (name, quantity, price)}
```

How can I print out the most expensive car? I've tried the following method, but it returned the highest ID (`3`):

```
most_expensive_car = max(dict, key=dict.get)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```python
>>> max(my_dict.items(), key=lambda t: int(t[1][2][:-3]))
('2:', ('BMW,', '150,', '12000USD'))
```

`my_dict.items()` will return a list of tuples with `key/value` pairs and the lambda will first get the value (`t[1]`), then the price (`[2]`) and finally remove the currency (`USD`) by using string slicing (`[:-3]`).

As a side note, don't use built-in names (such as `dict`) for your own variables and functions as they will shadow the built-in.